# PHP: Error :Syntax to be user near '='a_name','='another_name' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Below is the code where I'm getting error:

```
 $f1=$row['ParentName'];
 $f2=$row['Full_Name'];
 $f3=$row["Address_1"];
 $f4= $row['Address_2'];
 $f5=$row['City'];
 $f6=$row['State'];
 $f7=$row['Country'];
 $f9=$row['Contact_No'];

 $sql1="UPDATE login_signup ".
                           "SET $f1=' ".$_POST["pname"]." ',$f2= ' ".$_POST["fname"]." ', $f3= ' ".$_POST["addr1"]." ',$f4= ' ".$_POST["addr2"]." ',$f5= ' ".$_POST["city"]." ', $f6= ' ".$_POST["state"]." ',$f7= ' ".$_POST["country"]." ', $f9= ' ".$_POST["cn"]." ' ".
                           "WHERE $var= ' ".$_POST["email"]." '";
```

Error is something like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '=' ABCD ',= ' XYZ ', = ' dfgh ',= ' ZXCV ',= '' at line 1

ABCD,XYZ,ZXCV,dfgh--Submitted through form for fullname,parentname....respectively

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: just echo `$sql1` & see the row sql

Comment: You are using variable like `$f1`, `$f2` in your query instead of column name and are you sure these variables are not null?

Comment: ABCD,XYZ,ZXCV,dfgh are fine bcz they are not null but your variable like `$f1`,`$f2` are null.

Comment: Ya it was null. Forgot to assign default values. Thanks:)

Comment: $sql1="UPDATE login_signup SET '".$f1."'=' ".$_POST['pname']." ','".$f2."' = ' ".$_POST['fname']." ', '".$f3."'= ' ".$_POST['addr1']." ','".$f4."'= ' ".$_POST['addr2']." ','".$f5."'= ' ".$_POST['city']." ', '".$f6."'= ' ".$_POST['state']." ','".$f7."'= ' ".$_POST['country']." ', '".$f9."'= ' ".$_POST['cn']." '  WHERE '".$var."'= ' ".$_POST['email']."' ";

Comment: I have one more question.. How to assign a string value to an int ? I have a column, Contact_no and I'm sending 123456789 through post. Now how to assin this to $row['Contact_No'] ?

Comment: what is your next question?

Comment: I have one more question.. How to assign a string value to an int ? I have a column, Contact_no and I'm sending 123456789 through post. Now how to assin this to $row['Contact_No'] ? It is in the above code $f9.

Comment: ' ".$_POST['cn']." ' is a string of numbers

Comment: PHP is a loosely type language, where you don't need to assign data types just assign value and it will take data type automatically as per the value.

Comment: But I'm getting an error : error in syntax to use near '8212546789=' 08212548286 '   8212546789 is default value.

Comment: if this error coming in mysql query then your column name is `8212546789`. That's not possible. it should be an alphanumeric.

Comment: Column default value is 8212546789. And column name is Contact_Num. So the value of $row['Contact_Num'] is 8212546789.

Comment: echo your query and post here.

Comment: Yup..I'm getting 8212546789= 08212548286 and not the column name.. But why is that so?

Comment: Why are you using like this  `$f9=$row['Contact_No'];`   and then using `$f9` in query. If you know the column name keep them static in query,

Comment: If I use $row['Contact_No'] instead of $f9 it tells "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) "

Comment: If I use ' ".$row['Contact_No']." ' then it is taking the value of column name.

Comment: ok first tell me what is in `$row` array and from where it is coming?

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval); and $retval is result of the query 'SELECT * FROM login_signup'

Comment: and what is $retval? also post your query that you using using for $retval

Comment: $retval is result of the query 'SELECT * FROM login_signup';                         $retval = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

Comment: @Swathi You are doing it wrong.
If you want to update the table then use column name in query not query result. posting answer check this.

Comment: I want to update multiple columns

Comment: Echo your query and update the question with that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

Use column name of table instead of their value.

```
$sql1="UPDATE login_signup SET ParentName='".$_POST["pname"]."' , Full_Name= '".$_POST["fname"]."' , Address_1 = '".$_POST["addr1"]."' , Address_2 = '".$_POST["addr2"]."' , City= '".$_POST["city"]."' , State = '".$_POST["state"]."' , Country = '".$_POST["country"]."' , Contact_No= '".$_POST["cn"]."' WHERE $var= '".$_POST["email"]."' ";
```